# I can't load a MySQL table containing only integer columns from a file

Tags: mysql, import, load-data-infile

I'm trying to import data to a MySQL table.

The table :

```
CREATE TABLE `MYTABLE` (
  `F1` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `F2` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `F3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `F4` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `F5` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `F6` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `F7` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`F1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

The data file contains records of this form, which are separated by tab:

```
229733561174    44224449355443  0   0   0   55555557555000  12345678901
```

The import command :

```
mysql> load data infile 'try.txt' INTO TABLE MYTABLE;
```

The warnings I get:

| Level | Code | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '229733561174' for column 'F1' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '44224449355443' for column 'F2' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '0 0 0 55555557555000 12345678901' for column 'F3' at row 1 |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns |
| Warning | 1261 | Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns |

```
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I can't figure out why the values of the first two columns are `Incorrect integer value` and why the values of columns 3-7 are all treated as a single column.

I tried changing the field separator to ',' (specifying it in the load data command), and still got the same warnings.

The output table contains 0s in all columns (except for the optional column that gets NULL).

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try setting default value for your columns to 0.

Comment: @Mihai I tried - it didn't help. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The default character set in my DB was ucs2, which caused the problem.
If I specify a different character set in the `load data infile` command, everything works:

```
load data infile 'try.txt' ignore 
into table MYTABLE
character set latin1
fields terminated by '\t' enclosed by '' escaped by '\\'
lines terminated by '\n' starting by ''
ignore 1 lines;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please pls help me in this queestion.. i will remove my comment now .. http://stackoverflow.com/q/30316654/4538704

Answer (score 0):

This error implies that the data is not truly tab-delimited:

```
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '0  0       0       55555557555000
12345678901' for column 'F3' at row 1 |
```

Perhaps the first two delimiters are tabs, but the rest of them are variable numbers of spaces.

I recommend that you verify and standardize the way the fields are delimited.

It's also a good practice to explicitly declare the delimiter in the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, rather than relying on the defaults. For example:

```
load data infile 'try.txt' 
INTO TABLE MYTABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY '';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the tabs are not the problem. As I mentioned in my question, I tried to change the delimiters to ',' and added `fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '' escaped by '\\' lines terminated by '\n' starting by ''`, and got similar warnings. The first two columns are parsed correctly but give the 'Incorrect integer type' warning. The next 4 columns are all parsed as a single column - `0,0,0,55555557555000`, and the last one is parsed correctly.