# How can i get the values from the php arrray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wanted to take the fields such as ResumeParsingStartDate, ResumeParsingExpiryDate, MaxLimitOfParsedResume, NumberOfParsedResume

How can i take those valuse in php

Here is the [Eval Link](https://eval.in/367046)

Here is the array that i have

[Here is the updated code :](https://eval.in/367167)

Note : As stackoverflow's editor allows only 30,000 char the character has 35,000 char, and i can't able to decrease it anyway

Comment: Update your formatted code

Comment: Hi here is the formatted code : https://eval.in/367167 the array has exceeded the allowed max char

Comment: https://eval.in/367167 I have updated it in the question too :)

Comment: I want the api url ?

Comment: Here is the api url http://recruitplushrxmlapidemo.onlineresumeparser.com/hrxml/149Anne%20Marie%20Powell.xml

Comment: These are the information tags **<ResumeParsingStartDate>5/19/2015 3:43:11 PM</ResumeParsingStartDate>
<ResumeParsingExpiryDate>5/19/2016 3:43:11 PM</ResumeParsingExpiryDate>
<NumberOfParsedResume>1</NumberOfParsedResume>
<MaxLimitOfParsedResume>50000</MaxLimitOfParsedResume>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the single records like this :

```
    $url = 'http://recruitplushrxmlapidemo.onlineresumeparser.com/hrxml/149Anne%20Marie%20Powell.xml';

    $sxml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    echo 'ResumeParsingStartDate --> '.$sxml->ResumeAdditionalItems->ResumeAdditionalItem[1]->ResumeParsingStartDate;        
    echo "<br />";
    echo 'ResumeParsingExpiryDate --> '.$sxml->ResumeAdditionalItems->ResumeAdditionalItem[1]->ResumeParsingExpiryDate;        
    echo "<br />";
    echo 'NumberOfParsedResume --> '.$sxml->ResumeAdditionalItems->ResumeAdditionalItem[1]->NumberOfParsedResume;        
    echo "<br />";
    echo 'MaxLimitOfParsedResume --> '.$sxml->ResumeAdditionalItems->ResumeAdditionalItem[1]->MaxLimitOfParsedResume;        
    echo "<br />";
```

Use loop for repetitive elements

Comment: Thanks, as i am saving that file locally i am getting it from **$sxml = simplexml_load_file($FilesName);
echo 'ResumeParsingStartDate --> '.$sxml->ResumeAdditionalItems->ResumeAdditionalItem[1]->ResumeParsingStartDate;** Thanks :)